# Excel VBA: Why would file names sometimes truncate on save?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that takes data from the current row in an Excel workbook and generates another Excel workbook from a template and fills it in. (It also generates a couple Word documents and PDFs from the same data.) Generally, it works as intended.

But sometimes when it saves the generated workbook, the file name gets truncated. This truncation includes the file extension, so it doesn't even show as an Excel file in the folder, though renaming it to have `.xlsx` at the end fixes that issue.

The truncation is not consistent in length. The first line below is what the file name should be (and sometimes is) and the second two lines are examples of how this file name has been truncated.

```
Grant Fiscal Accountability Workbook-Xxxxxx  Yyyyy Zzzzz Childhood Education Center.xlsx
Grant Fiscal Accountability Workbook-Xxxxxx  Yyyyy Zzzzz Childhood Educati
Grant Fiscal Accountability Workbook-Xxxxxx  Yyyyy Zzzzz Childhood Education Center.xl
```

The truncation seems to happen more often:

- When the macro is run from (and writing to) a Onedrive folder.
- When my coworker is running it on her machine. (Her personal laptop she uses to work from home.)
- With longer file names; the longer they are, the more likely it is.

In light of all that, it feels like the process that's writing the file name is just bailing if things take too long, but I have trouble imagining why something that simple would run into time constraints or fail without throwing an error.

The other possibility I considered was that I was bumping up against the maximum path length in Windows. I'm not sure what's happening behind the scenes on Onedrive, but on my machine it truncated well short of 260 characters. (Not that it should matter since I'm on Windows 10, but I wanted to be sure.)

The following code is my effort at an MCVE.

```
Sub GenerateDocuments()
    'Variable for This Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
    
    Dim templateFolder As String
    templateFolder = wb.Path
        
    'The path where we want to generate the new folder. Value from the configuration worksheet.
    Dim savePath As String
    savePath = wb.Worksheets("Configuration").Range("B3").Value
    
    Dim facilityName As String
    facilityName = "Test Facility Ridicuous length 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789"
    
    'The newly generated folder.
    Dim saveFolder As String
    saveFolder = CreateEvalFolder(savePath, facilityName)
    
    
    CreateFiscalAccountabilityWorkbook facilityName, templateFolder, saveFolder
    

End Sub



Sub CreateFiscalAccountabilityWorkbook(facilityName As String, templateFolder As String, saveFolder As String)
    'create the word app
    Dim exApp As Excel.Application
    Set exApp = New Excel.Application
    'show what's happening, rather than running in the background
    exApp.Visible = True
    
    'create a new document from the template
    Dim FAWWorkbook As Workbook
    Set FAWWorkbook = exApp.Workbooks.Add(templateFolder + "\Grant Fiscal Accountability Workbook-.xltx")
    
    
    FAWWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=saveFolder & "\Grant Fiscal Accountability Workbook-" & ValidWBName(facilityName), FileFormat:=xlWorkbookDefault
    
End Sub



Function CreateEvalFolder(savePath As String, facilityName As String) As String
    Dim pathString As String
    'homepath makes this more portable.
    pathString = Environ("HOMEPATH") + savePath + "\" + ValidWBName(facilityName)


    If Len(Dir(pathString, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then MkDir pathString

    CreateEvalFolder = pathString

End Function


'https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/remove-all-restricted-characters-from-save-file-name.668753/
Private Function ValidWBName(Arg As String) As String
    Dim RegEx As Object
    Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With RegEx
        .Pattern = "[\\/:\*\?""<>\|]"
        .Global = True
        ValidWBName = .Replace(Arg, " ")
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: This [Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/error-message-when-you-open-or-save-a-file-in-microsoft-excel-filename-is-not-valid-951229f3-dc14-980f-765e-224e4fdc7331) post mentions the following: *Make sure that the path to the file contains fewer than 219 characters*

Comment: Another thing to take notice of is accented characters and non-latin characters. It shouldn't matter but it might.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [this Microsoft support document](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/error-message-when-you-open-or-save-a-file-in-microsoft-excel-filename-is-not-valid-951229f3-dc14-980f-765e-224e4fdc7331) (hat tip to @MarceloPaco):

> This behavior is based on a 256-character limitation in Excel for
> creating links to another file. This **limit of 218 characters** for
> the path name is based on the following:
>
> - Up to 31 characters in a sheet name.
> - Apostrophes and brackets used to denote the workbook name.
> - An exclamation point.
> - A cell reference.

**After some testing, it does appear that 218 is the magic number at which the file name is truncated.** (This would also explain why my coworker is running into this issue more often; she has access to folders higher up the Onedrive tree than I do, so her paths are longer.)